# Invalid html attribute

Tags: html

It seems there's an issue with my HTML syntax.

> The `*data-toggle="minimize"` attribute is not a valid HTML attribute. If you're trying to use Bootstrap's `data-toggle="minimize"` functionality, you should remove the asterisk (*).

Here's the button code:

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler align-self-center" type="button" *data-toggle="minimize">
    <span class="icon-menu"></span>
</button>
```

It's not working at vue.js and laravel. Please help me

Answer (score 1):

> you should remove the asterisk (*).

So you just need to remove the '*' before data

```
<button class="navbar-toggler navbar-toggler align-self-center" type="button" data-toggle="minimize">
```

[Here are the docs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#embedding-custom-non-visible-data-with-the-data-*-attributes) for data-* attributes.